# My update code updates more than one field?

Tags: mysql

Strange one this, I have a database set up with these fields:

```
EmailConfirmID  
EmailToConfirm                              
ConfirmCode         
DateRequested   
DandTConfirmed
```

When I run this bit of sql:

```
UPDATE Emails2Confirm 
SET 
    DandTConfirmed = NOW()
WHERE
    EmailToConfirm = 'testfri@testfri.com' AND ConfirmCode = 'whatever';
```

It changes BOTH DateRequested and DandTConfirmed to the current time. No clue why, all advice appreciated!

Comment: I'll bet `DateRequested` has `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in its definition. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE Emails2Confirm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the `DateRequested` column presumably has the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so any time you modify any other column, it will be updated to the current time.